# GLPK Timeout (tm_lim) returns best solution found?

Tags: glpk

My experiments (using the C library directly) suggest that using the tm_lim parameter to limit the time taken by GLPK on a mixed integer programming problem results in a problem pointer that contains the best solution found so far. However, I can't find any confirmation of this in the documentation. Does a timed-out computation always leave the best discovered solution in the problem buffer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tm_lim` parameter does indeed return the best solution from my anecdotal experience. I could not find verification of this in the documentation either, so I looked at the source.

glpk iterates over a loop, updating the solution in-place until one of four termination criteria (optimal solution, unbounded solution, time limit, iteration limit) is satisfied. Once this happens, glpk stops updating the solution and returns a value indicating the satisfied criterion.

You can verify this in the function `ssx_phase_II` in `src/glpssx02.c` in https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/glpk-4.35.tar.gz. Look at references to `tm_lim`.

A final piece of justification is the documentation for the `--tmlim` command line option:

```
--tmlim nnn limit solution time to nnn seconds (--tmlim 0 allows
            obtaining solution at initial point)
```

Passing `--tmlim 0` would return the initial solution.